# how to use hashmap to find smallest mode in the array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dictionary

The question is that given an array returns the most frequently occurring element of an array of positive integers. Assume that the array has at least one element .If there are more than one mode return the smallest mode.

Here is my code, but it can not pass this array {27, 15, 15, 11, 27}.

Also,how to modify my code without using `i` in for-each loop?

```
    public int mode(int input[]){
    if(input.length==1)
        return input[0];
    Map<Integer,Integer> mymap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    int count=0;
    for(int i = 0 ;i < input.length;i++){
        count = mymap.containsKey(input[i]) ? mymap.get(input[i]) : 0;
         mymap.put(input[i],count+1);
    }
    int firstmode = -1;
    int secondmode = -1;
    int i=0;
    for(int k :mymap.keySet()){
        if(mymap.get(k)>secondmode){
            i++;
            firstmode=k;
            if(i%2==0){ //if there more than one mode,then compare them
                if(firstmode>k){
                   firstmode=k;
                   i--;
                }
            }
        secondmode=mymap.get(k);
        }  
    }
    return firstmode;
}
```

Updated test cases

```
{1, 1, 2, 3}    should return 1 
{1, 1, 2, 3, 3} should return 1
{27, 15, 15, 11, 27}    should return 15    
{27, 15, 15, 11, 27, 27}    should return 27    
{1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3}    should return 3 
{27, 15, 15, 27, 11, 11, 11, 14, 15, 15, 16, 19, 99, 100, 0, 27}    
should return 15    
{42}    should return 42
```

Comment: Question: What do you mean by mode? Do you mean smallest value which is occurring most frequently? Can you provide couple of examples array where your code works correctly and output of the above array which is incorrect?

Comment: @alwaysANewbie .The mode is the value that appears most often in a set of data.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)

Comment: Stream.of(input).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting())).firstKey()

Comment: Yes but what does it mean to find the 'smallest mode'? Let's say you have the number `3` which occurs `4` times, then the number `4` which occurs `5` times. Which one is the smallest? You might say `3` because it's smaller than `4`, but `3` only occurs `4` times while `4` occurs `5` times. This question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your logic pretty unclear and convoluted so I just rewrote the code from scratch. I included a solution pre-Java 8 and another one post-Java 8.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.IntStream;

import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;

public class Solution {
    public static int smallestMode(int input[]) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();
        for (Integer i : input) {
            Integer counter = counters.get(i);
            counters.put(i, counter == null ? 1 : counter + 1);
        }

        int mode = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int counter : counters.values()) mode = Math.max(mode, counter);

        int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : counters.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() == mode) result = Math.min(result, entry.getKey());
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static int smallestModeJava8(int input[]) {
        Map<Integer, Long> counters = IntStream.of(input).boxed().collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()));
        long mode = counters.values().stream().max(naturalOrder()).get();
        return counters.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == mode).map(Map.Entry::getKey).min(naturalOrder()).get();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = {27, 15, 15, 11, 27};
        System.out.println(smallestMode(input));
        System.out.println(smallestModeJava8(input));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your pre-Java 8 version still relies on a Java 8 add-on: `Map.merge()`

Comment: By the way if you have a one-liner for creating the map of counters I will take it. I found Java 8 streams particularly ugly for doing such simple thing (hate their *collector* approach)

Comment: @Dici, Do you know how to write it in Jave 7? How do you find smallest mode if there are more than one mode?

Comment: I included both Java 7 (or less) and Java 8 (or more) solutions. The last loop is the one that picks the smallest mode

Comment: `Map<Integer, Integer> counters = Arrays.stream(input).boxed().collect(toMap(k -> k, v -> 1, Integer::sum));`

Comment: @shmosel sweet, I did not know this version of `toMap`. Thanks !

Comment: Or you can use `groupingBy(k -> k, reducing(1, Integer::sum))`. Not shorter, but possible clearer.

Comment: Or `groupingBy(k -> k, counting())`, but that'll give you `Map<Integer, Long>`.

Comment: Great, you're more proficient than me with Java streams. I've got used to a more Scalatic style. The one using `counting()` will be less expensive though, of the three of them that's my favourite

Comment: The thing that I dislike with this API is that I find it less discoverable than a more classic collection API where all the methods are on the collection itself (like `input.groupBy(identity).maValues(_.length)` in Scala for example)and not on some collectors that you need to discover and compose

Comment: I agree. I always find myself typing `[stream].toList()` instead of `[stream].collect(toList())`. Take a look at [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) for a more fluent syntax.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks. I guess they did it for extensibility. By implementing new collectors, users can support more specific use-cases like `stream.collect(toImmutableList())`. Anyway, this is still much more concise than plain old Java so I won't complain :D

Comment: Since you like one-liners, here's another for you: `return Arrays.stream(input).boxed().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting())).entrySet().stream().min(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByValue().reversed().thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())).map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(-1);`

Comment: Sweet, although I would put it on several lines :D why don't you post your own answer to showcase all those different methods ?